# Play: Bind a form field to a double?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Perhaps I'm just overlooking something obvious but I can't figure out how to bind a form field to a double in a Play controller.

For instance, assume this is my model:

```
case class SavingsGoal(
timeframeInMonths: Option[Int],
amount: Double,
name: String
)
```

(Ignore that I'm using a double for money, I know that's a bad idea, this is just a simplified example)

And I wanted to bind it like so:

```
object SavingsGoals extends Controller {

    val savingsForm: Form[SavingsGoal] = Form(

        mapping(
            "timeframeInMonths" -> optional(number.verifying(min(0))),
            "amount" -> of[Double],
            "name" -> nonEmptyText
        )(SavingsGoal.apply)(SavingsGoal.unapply)

    )

}
```

I realized that the `number` helper only works for ints but I thought using `of[]` might allow me to bind a double.  However, I get a compiler error on this:

```
Cannot find Formatter type class for Double. Perhaps you will need to import
play.api.data.format.Formats._
```

Doing so doesn't help as there's no double formatter defined in the API.

This is all just a long way of asking what's the canonical way of binding a form field to a double in Play?

Thanks!

edit: 4e6 pointed me in the right direction.  Here's what I did using his help:

Using the snippets in his link, I added the following to app.controllers.Global.scala:

```
object Global {

    /**
     * Default formatter for the `Double` type.
     */
    implicit def doubleFormat: Formatter[Double] = new Formatter[Double] {

      override val format = Some("format.real", Nil)

      def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) =
        parsing(_.toDouble, "error.real", Nil)(key, data)

      def unbind(key: String, value: Double) = Map(key -> value.toString)
    }

    /**
     * Helper for formatters binders
     * @param parse Function parsing a String value into a T value, throwing an exception in case of failure
     * @param error Error to set in case of parsing failure
     * @param key Key name of the field to parse
     * @param data Field data
     */
    private def parsing[T](parse: String => T, errMsg: String, errArgs: Seq[Any])(key: String, data: Map[String, String]): Either[Seq[FormError], T] = {
      stringFormat.bind(key, data).right.flatMap { s =>
        util.control.Exception.allCatch[T]
          .either(parse(s))
          .left.map(e => Seq(FormError(key, errMsg, errArgs)))
      }
    }

}
```

Then, in my form mapping:

```
mapping(
    "amount" -> of(Global.doubleFormat)
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, [there is](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/format/Format.scala#L117) predefined formatter for `Double` on master branch. So you should either switch to `2.1-SNAPSHOT` play version or just copy the implementation.

Comment: Thanks!  That works perfectly.  I'll update my original question with my solution in case anyone else stumbles upon this.

Comment: As of this writing, the link to `doubleFormat` is here https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/b7c414ef11a1a8befa0caa8dbc52fa4e11128a08/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/format/Format.scala#L132 (Pro tip: press "y" in github to a get a permalink tied to a particular commit. Since "master" moves over time, master-based links rot over time.)

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to use the the format in the global if you have the version 2.1 up.

Just import:

```
import play.api.data.format.Formats._
```

and use as:

```
mapping(
    "amount" -> of(doubleFormat)
)
```