# How can I handle decimal numbers using the Scala framework play

Tags: scala, playframework, decimal

I want to be able to enter decimal numbers into a play form.  I would like to have the following mapping, but it does not compile.

```
mapping(
 "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Pk[Long]),
 "date" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd"),
 "amount" -> decimal,
 "description" -> nonEmptyText
)(Expense.apply)(Expense.unapply)
```

There must be a way. I am very new to Scala and Play.  Any pointers, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is method `of[T]` on object [`Forms`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Forms%24), that creates mapping of type `T`. In your case it would be `of[Int]`:

```
mapping(
 "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Pk[Long]),
 "date" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd"),
 "amount" -> of[Int],
 "description" -> nonEmptyText
)(Expense.apply)(Expense.unapply)
```

There are also two helper methods

```
val number: Mapping[Int] = of[Int]
val longNumber: Mapping[Long] = of[Long]
```

which are just reference generic `of` function.

Comment: But I want to use decimal numbers not integers ie (5.45)

Comment: Then use `of[Double]` mapping. See [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759430/play-bind-a-form-field-to-a-double/12760279) for details.

Comment: My model has a field with type BigDecimal so I cannot use of[Double]. 

I have looked at the linked question and I guess I just need to do the same thing but for BigDecimal. 

I am just confused as to why it would not already be in the code base. I thought that perhaps I was missing something and there is another, standard way of handle this scenario.

Comment: Developers can't forsee everything that user may need. At best they provide generic solution, that can be refined according to requirements. If you need `Formatter[BigDecimal]` it's not too hard to implement.

Answer (score 3):

As of [this pull request](https://github.com/Timshel/Play20/commit/b78865f0e759cf02d36b75986d9b686ac1eff04e) you can now specify [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) as a type of input. Modifying the OP's Example:

```
mapping(
 "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Pk[Long]),
 "date" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd"),
 "amount" -> bigDecimal,
 "description" -> nonEmptyText
)(Expense.apply)(Expense.unapply)
```

Note the **bigDecimal** mapping type.

For further precision and scale you can specify them as:

```
 "amount" -> bigDecimal(10, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the actual code for the implicit you need. I put them in a separate object because I have a lot of these for my own types too. It's very handy to be able to use custom types in `Form`s this way.

```
object FormFieldImplicits {
  // Code merged into future Play release
  //
  implicit def doubleFormat = new Formatter[Double] {
    def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) = Right(data(key).toDouble)
    def unbind(key: String, value: Double) = Map(key -> value.toString)
  }

  ...
}
```

Then just `import FormFieldImplicits._` in your controller where you want to use a `mapping` `of[Double]` and Bob's your uncle as follows

```
def impactMapping = mapping(
    "value" -> of[Double],
    "percent" -> of[Double])(Impact.apply)(Impact.unapply)
```